# Video blinking problem at full-screen

Tags: video

Recently I installed ubuntu 20.04 in my Lenovo s145 laptop along with windows 10. All videos are playing well when screen is minimized. But it starts blinking when i turn it into fullscreen. I tried VLC player, but it is happening with all player. And full-screen video playing all window extends beyond monitor, can't find close icon.
[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xsTk.jpg)

[Window extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gSZL.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Heyy, I was facing a similar issue. It is due to the change in display settings we've done before. Go to display settings and revert back the fractional scaling to 100% if it is not. Ubuntu version 20.04

Comment: I will have to buy a telescope to see my screen now... :P Thanks for the solution. Now let's wait for a solution or a workaround for the flickering when scaling is 125%+

Answer (score 1):

Better late than never for those who may face this issue. Going to Preferences -> Monitor Settings you'll find the refresh rate for HDMI (which I am using). This was on 60Hz and I set it to 59.9xx Hz. After that the flickering in fullscreen mode was gone.

BTW: I am on Lubuntu 20.04 on a Zotac Mini PC.

Comment: This solved my issue. I had fractional scaling which caused the problem. I could've disabled the scaling but reducing FPS also worked.